# why my context doesn't update when the context value updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-context

so I am using React's context API in my Gatsby app(which is written in React basically) to deal with user authentication. I have two components that use that context: `dashboard` and `navBar`. When I try to log in and log out, my `navBar` will behave differently according to my `userContext`, but my `dashboard` won't respond. Is it something related to the structure, like `navBar` is the direct "children" to `layout`, but `dashboard` is not? I assume not though, after all, that's why I use `contextAPI` then just pass a normal prop.

Here are the codes:

```
//layout.js
import React, { useContext, useState, createContext } from "react"
import Navbar from "../components/navBar"
import {monitorAuth} from "../firebase/firebaseService"

export const UserStateContext = createContext(null)
export const SetUserContext = createContext()

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState()
  console.log(user)

  monitorAuth(setUser)// everytime a layout component renders, it will grab a user if it is logged inthen setUser, then I will use it in the context

  return (
    <>
      <UserStateContext.Provider value={user}>
        <SetUserContext.Provider value={setUser}>
          <div>
            <SEO />
            <Navbar />
            <main>{children}</main>
          </div>
        </SetUserContext.Provider >
      </UserStateContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}


export default Layout
```

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react"
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar"
import { signOut } from "../firebase/firebaseService"
import {UserStateContext} from "./layout"

export default function NavBar() {
  const user = useContext(UserStateContext)
  console.log(user) // when I log in/ log out, it will console.log the right user status, user/null

  const renderMenu = () => {
    return (
    <>
      {user? (
      <>
      <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</Button>
      <Button>My profile</Button> 
      </>)
     :<Button>Sign In</Button> }
    </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <AppBar position="static" className={classes.root}>
        ...
        {renderMenu()}
        ...
  </AppBar>
  )
}
```

```
//dashboard.js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import LoggedIn from '../components/dashboard/loggedIn'
import NotLoggedIn from '../components/dashboard/notLoggedIn'
import {UserStateContext} from "../components/layout"


const Dashboard = props => {
    console.log("within dashboard")
    const user = useContext(UserStateContext)
    console.log(user)

    const renderDashboard = () =>{
       return (
         <>
         {user? <LoggedIn /> : <NotLoggedIn />}
         </>
         
       )
    }

    return(
      <Layout>
        {renderDashboard()}
      </Layout>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

One more clue, I console.log `user` in all three components and when I refresh the page:

```
within dashboard
dashboard.js:17 null
layout.js:15 undefined
navBar.jsx:54 undefined
layout.js:15 [user...]
navBar.jsx:54 [user...]
layout.js:15 [user...]
```

That means, at first, `user` is not set yet, so all three components log the `user` as `undefined`, but later, `layout` detect the `user` and then updates it, so `navbar`knows too, but `dashboard` doesn't. Is it something about `re-render`? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use two contexts for this? You can combine them. Also i never see u re-use `SetUserContext` you need to call `setUser` to trigger a render

Comment: I gave it a try to combine them and it should work, if you follow [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-darwin-b1ex9?file=/src/App.js) :)

Comment: You have to call your setter in order to update your context state.

Comment: @Stutje Thank you! The reason I use two different contexts is that it prevents from too much re-render. But thanks for doing the code-pen :) It is just part of the codes, I would use the SetUserContext somewhere else, and setUser is used in `monitorAuth` to set the user's value

Comment: @JULIENPICARD I did.  It is just part of the codes, I would use the SetUserContext somewhere else, and `setUser` is used in `monitorAuth` to set the user's value

Comment: @Ethan did we help you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Stutje Thank you! But I think paulshen actually got the right answer. It is my mistake

Comment: @Ethan Np, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because your `<Dashboard>` component is not a child of the context provider. If you use React devtools, you'll see the component tree looks like

```
<Dashboard>
  <Layout>
    <UserStateContext.Provider>
      <SetUserContext.Provider>
        ...
      </SetUserContext.Provider> 
    </UserStateContext.Provider> 
  </Layout>
</Dashboard>
```

When the context value changes, it looks for components in its subtree that `useContext`. However, `Dashboard` is not a child, it's the parent!

If you want to follow this pattern, a solution may be to create a parent component of `Dashboard` and put the context there.